# Replicating a 'production/live' server (wamp)

Tags: php, testing, php-5.3, wampserver, case-sensitive

I am running a wamp test/development server on my rig, however I am trying to ensure it replicates the normal behavior of a production server. Last time I moved from a test environment to a live one I had the following issues:

1. Case sensitive relative paths were being obnoxious on the live server
2. Case sensitive MySQL commands were being obnoxious on the live server
3. Some header requests I sent (okay this is embarrassing) in the middle of a 'view' were obviously not getting accepted.

I replicated the behavior of error number 3 on my test server by disabling output_buffer in the ini file.

However, I haven't quiet figured out how to make my test server all touchy about case sensitive paths and sql commands.

Could someone help me out? Also, please point out the other settings I should enable/disable in the ini file to ensure it acts like a live server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble is that your live server is a non-Windows server, and your test server is a Windows server.  PHP is relying on the system to find files.  Windows files/paths are not case sensitive.

For everything else, you are likely using different versions of MySQL and what not.

If you want a solid test, either upload directly to your live server, or duplicate the server and run it in a virtual machine, such as [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/), on your dev computer.

Comment: That makes sense, appreciate the help! I will look into VMWare.